# Liferay Velocity Structure and Template. Repeatable Fields

Tags: templates, liferay, structure, velocity

I am using a structure a little like this with levelOne and levelTwo both being repeatable.

```
levelOne
    levelTwo
        levelThree
```

When using  a foreach loop to display the data I can only seem to find the first instance of levelTwo and levelThree. I have tried an absolute ton of methods to try and grab this information but i'm beginning to wonder if it is outside of Velocitys capabilities.

Even when I just grab the data from levelOne and display all of it with

```
#foreach($i in $levelOne.getSiblings())
  <p>$i</p>
#end
```

all that I get displayed is

```
{name=levelOne, data=levelOneData, type=text, options=[],
levelTwo={name=levelTwo, data=levelTwoData, type=text, options=[],
levelThree={name=levelThree, data=levelThreeData, type=text, options=[]}}}
```

when using a nested foreach like so

```
#foreach($i in $levelOne.getSiblings())
 #foreach($j in $i.getSiblings())
   <p>$j</p>
 #end
#end
```

I get the same result..

There is no information displayed about the repeated data in levelTwo. Does anyone know if this is a waste of time trying to figure out or if there is something i'm missing?

Comment: Excuse me, I understand what you write, but I'm not sure about what is your question. :) I would try to help you, so please, can you report what do you want to know exactly?

Comment: No, I'm not following Liferay site in the last days... :)

Comment: How random. I asked a similar question and the person who responded has the username Pier Paolo

Comment: Wow... surprising... :) If I'm not in wrong I'm just "pierpaolo" on Liferay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Solution is as follows..

```
#foreach($i in $levelOne.getSiblings())
  #foreach($j in $i.levelTwo.getSiblings())
    <p>$j</p>
  #end
#end
```

Comment: I think is not correct to auto-reply to your question (using my answer), then to choose your answer as best one. In this case you should choose mine as best answer, then to comment it.

Comment: Yes, sure... :) The misunderstanding borne because of your structure was (almost for me) not clearly defined in the question... and it leads for the unusual need to loop over siblings of a child...

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand your situation.
If you need to know how many siblings exist for a variable, you can use `$yourVar.getSiblings().size()`: it returns the size of the siblings list.

This is why a code like `#foreach($i in $levelOne.getSiblings())` works.

The following output shows that you have just one sibling (I indent it for simplifying reading):

```
{
name=levelOne,
data=levelOneData,
type=text,
options=[],
levelTwo={
    name=levelTwo,
    data=levelTwoData,
    type=text,
    options=[],
    levelThree={
        name=levelThree,
        data=levelThreeData,
        type=text,
        options=[]}
    }
}
```

Going forward... I'm sure you can work with nested lists and maps in Velocity... so my first question is: are you sure that inside your variable you have more than one instance of Leve2 and Level3?

To better understand try to modify the second part of code you reported as follow

```
<p>$levelOne</p>
<hr />
#foreach($i in $levelOne.getSiblings())
    <p><strong>$i</strong></p>
    #foreach($j in $i.getSiblings())
        <p>$j</p>
    #end
    <hr />
#end
```

What do you see now?
Is it possible you have a problem with your `$i` before loops?

But (second question)... if I'm not well understanding your structure... and you need something of different... do you know the `getChildren()` method of Velocity variables?

Comment: See this also: https://www.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/2777824